# AWS WAF controlling CloudFront app access to API ALB in tiered arch design

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-application-load-balancer, amazon-waf

I've been going at this now for a few days with no success. I am attempting to do what is being described here, modified for a two tier architecture:

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-enhance-amazon-cloudfront-origin-security-with-aws-waf-and-aws-secrets-manager/

Which is limit public access to the ALB that serves the API layer but engaging the custom header strategy AWS describes in their blog.

And illustrated here (dB tier not included):

[image: tiered arch]

The header coming from CloudFront does not seem to be interpreted and the request is blocked based on the default rule.

Redacted CloudWatch Logs:

`"timestamp":1681327911085,"formatVersion":1,"webaclId":"arn:aws:.....","terminatingRuleId":"Default_Action","terminatingRuleType":"REGULAR","action":"BLOCK","terminatingRuleMatchDetails":[],"requestHeadersInserted":null,"responseCodeSent":403,"httpRequest":{"clientIp":"X.X.X.X","country":"US","headers":[{"name":"host","value":"api.example.com"},{"name":"pragma","value":"no-cache"},{"name":"cache-control","value":"no-cache"},{"name":"accept","value":"*/*"},{"name":"access-control-request-method","value":"POST"},{"name":"access-control-request-headers","value":"content-type"},{"name":"origin","value":"https://app.example.com"},{"name":"user-agent","value":"Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/111.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"},{"name":"sec-fetch-mode","value":"cors"},{"name":"sec-fetch-site","value":"same-site"},{"name":"sec-fetch-dest","value":"empty"},{"name":"referer","value":"https://app.example.com/"},{"name":"accept-encoding","value":"gzip, deflate, br"},{"name":"accept-language","value":"en-US,en;q=0.9"}],"uri":"/path","args":"","httpVersion":"HTTP/2.0","httpMethod":"OPTIONS","requestId":"xxx"}`

Browser interprets it as a CORS policy error:
`Access to fetch at 'https://api.example.com/path' from origin 'https://app.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy`

The API is a home-grown REST API that is **NOT** served by AWS-API-Gateway.

I have also unsuccessfully tried to do this with a WAF IP Set rule based on CloudFront IPs. Same issue.

What am I missing here?

Comment: So I think I understand why it is NOT working, the header is only relevant to the origin, which in this case is the S3 static content bucket. But I still have not found a way to block public traffic to the API, while only allowing the application on CloudFront to access the API.